# The prompt() method must be called with a user gesture error in angular PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I have developed PWA in my angular project, PWA install banner is showing up on the chrome browser by calling the `prompt()` event like below,

```
this.promptEvent = event;
this.promptEvent.prompt();
```

but sometimes it is throwing an error

> The prompt() method must be called with a user gesture.

I couldn't find a solution to this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Trigger `prompt()` with a user action like a button click, don´t do it immediately after deferring the event.

```js
    var promptEvent; 

    // Capture event and defer
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        promptEvent = e;
        listenToUserAction();
    });

    // listen to install button clic
    function listenToUserAction() {
        const installBtn = document.querySelector(".install-btn");
        installBtn.addEventListener("click", presentAddToHome);
    }
    
    // present install prompt to user
    function presentAddToHome() {
        promptEvent.prompt();  // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
        promptEvent.userChoice
          .then(choice => {
              if (choice.outcome === 'accepted') {
                  console.log('User accepted');
              } else {
                  console.log('User dismissed');
              }
          })
    }
```

Link to a complete tutorial https://love2dev.com/blog/beforeinstallprompt

Take note this will only work in SOME browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent#Browser_compatibility

Comment: This didn't help. I am calling the `prompt()` method on a button click but still getting the error. Here's my code:
https://gist.github.com/murtuzaalisurti/785b2cb359bc7d996ebcc3539a67528b

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to solve the problem:

```
const handleInstallWebApp = () => {
  const deferredPrompt = window.deferredPrompt;
  if (deferredPrompt) {
    deferredPrompt.prompt();
    deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the install prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the install prompt');
      }
      window.deferredPrompt = null;
    });
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  const handleBeforeInstallPrompt = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.deferredPrompt = event;
    handleInstallWebApp();
  };

  const a = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style = 'display: none';
  a.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', handleBeforeInstallPrompt);

    window.removeEventListener(
      'beforeinstallprompt',
      handleBeforeInstallPrompt
    );
  });
  a.click();
}, []);
```